# How do I remove the correct fragment instance Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've recently started android app development, and have run into a problem I can't find a solution for.

When the user presses a button, the activity adds a fragment into a table.  The user can then add as many instances of this fragment as they want (each one showing up on a new row in the table).  This works perfectly.

The problem comes when the user clicks a button to delete a fragment.  Each fragment has its own delete button, but no matter which one the user clicks, the bottom row is always deleted.  How do I make it delete the correct fragment?

Below is all relevant code, including the creation of the fragments.  If I did the creation wrong, please tell me and tell me how I should be doing it.

An explanation of what is happening with some of the syntax would be incredibly helpful!

The main Activity:

```
public class WorkingOut extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int numOfSets = 0;
    private static FragmentManager fm;

    ...

    private void initialize(){

        ...

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    public void addSet(View view) {
        WorkoutSets newSet = new WorkoutSets();
       fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.set_container, newSet, "set_" + numOfSets).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    public static void removeSet(String tag){
        Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        fm.beginTransaction().detach(frag).commit();
        //fm.beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
    }
```

The Fragment Activity:

```
public class WorkoutSets extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    public WorkoutSets() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_sets, null);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WorkingOut.removeSet(getTag());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Main Activity Table XML:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rest_for_message"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/set_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false">

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/set_container"
                android:minHeight="10dp">
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Set"
                android:id="@+id/add_set"
                android:onClick="addSet"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/set_container"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The fragment remove button XML:

```
<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

FIXED

Both of the solutions below work.
I feel kind of dumb, because I specifically set up the tag system so each would have their own tag, then forgot to increment it -_-"
Thanks to both answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `addSet()` method you are adding each fragment with the same tag name. Hence when removing any fragment, only the last added (which is on top of the stack) fragment is removed.
You can change it to the following.

```
public void addSet(View view) {
        WorkoutSets newSet = new WorkoutSets();
       fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.set_container, newSet, "set_" + numOfSets++).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you said each Fragment contains the delete button, then you really don't have to do that much. Fragments have their own "getFragmentManager()" method that returns the exact same FragmentManager that put them there.

So, in your delete method, just do this:

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .remove(WorkoutSets.this).commit();
     }
});
```